# Display a particular row in datagridview based on the selection of the childnode from the treegridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, treeview

I have an hierarchy like this.

```
          +GroupID
          ------StringID
          ------StringID
          ------StringID
          +GroupID
          ------StringID
```

Now I know how to display the particular rows in the `datagridview` when the GroupID's are clicked. But I don't know how to get the value of the currently selected node in the tree when the StringID's are clicked and display it on the `datagridview` based on both the GroupID and the StringID*.

Here is the code for the GroupID selected and display on the `datagridview`:

```
    private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        int outva;
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        if (int.TryParse((e.Node.Text), out outva))
        {
            save=Convert.ToInt16(e.Node.Text);

            int row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Groupid =" +save;
        }
        else {
        //    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false ;
           // dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any errors i am asking that how to check when the stringid(child node) is clicked because whenever any node is clicked this event fires and it doesn't handle stringid's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some tips:

1. you are casting 2 times, when 1 is enough (outva is holding your id, so convert is not needed)
2. node mouse click is fired for nodes/children, you have to somehow determine what type is clicked (group id or string id). For example check if node has parent, if so it is string id or if node has children it is group id

   ```
   private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
   {
       int outva;
       dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

       if (int.TryParse((e.Node.Text), out outva))
       {
           //save=Convert.ToInt16(e.Node.Text);  //not needed

           string filterBy;

           if (e.Node.Parent != null)
           {
               filterBy = "GroupId = " + outva;
           }
           else
           {
               filterBy = "StringId = " outva;
           }

           //int row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count; // not needed

           ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = filterBy;
       }
       else 
       {

       }
   }
   ```

of course ther mayebe some improvements needed depending on how you create your tree.